# Replace img with its data attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var t = "";
$("div.postswrapper[data-value="+id2+"]").find("div.text.mainpost").children("p").each(function(p){
    t+= $(this).text().trim()+"\n";
});
```

I have this at the moment and its job is to take all the paragraph tags and add them to a string. Pretty simple. Now the hard part I am at is this:

The paragraphs may contain 0 to n img tags in them. eg

```
<p>hello<img src='https.imgur/image.png' data-raw='[img]https.imgur/image.png[/img]'>world!</p>
```

There's a string in each of the tags containing some raw data which I need to replace the image tags with as a string. For example, above would be

hello[img]https.imgur/image.png[/img]world!

I have tried

```
t+= $((this).find('img').replaceWith($(this).find('img').attr('data-raw')).text()).text().trim()+"\n";
```

but it failed horribly on due to (this).find function not existing in the current context

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use find to find img tag then use replaceWith function

```
 var t = "";
$("div.postswrapper[data-value="+id2+"]").find("div.text.mainpost").children("p").each(f unction(p){
p.find('img').replaceWith(function() { return this.data-raw;     });
 t+= $(this).text().trim()+"\n";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('[data-raw]');
Array.from(images).forEach((image) => {      
  image.parentElement.replaceChild(
    document.createTextNode(image.getAttribute('data-raw')), 
    image
  );
})
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say raw, are you referring to the base-64 encoding of the image data?

So your code may work soemthing like:

`` $("div.postswrapper[data-value="+id2+"]").find("div.text.mainpost").children("p").each(function(p){
p.find('img').attr('src', `data:image/png;base64, ${this.data-raw}`);     });
 t+= $(this).text().trim()+"\n";
}); ``